# What is the relation between $H(a;b)$ and $H(b;a)$, where $H$ is Hadamard matrix.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

For the definition of Hadamard matrix, please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix .

In the question, $a$ and $b$ are column vectors,  $(a;b)$ is a new column vector by stacking $a$ over $b$, $H(a;b)$ is the matrix-vector multiplication of $H$ and $(a;b)$.

If I have the result of $H(a;b)$, then how can I get $H(b;a)$ without explicitly calculating it?